# Calculate sum of two dynamically created textboxes using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<table id="tbl" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Mark1</th>
    <th>Mark2</th>
    <th>Total</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="cell"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="cell"></td>
    <td><b><span id="total_sum_value"></span></b></td>
    <td><b><span id="total_sum_value1"></span></b></td>
    <th><input class="add-row" data-id="1" type="button" value="+"></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var i = $(".add-row").data("id");

  $(".add-row").click(function(){
    $('#tbl').append('<tr><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>');
    var two = $("input").addClass("cell"+i);

    $("#tbl").on('input','.cell'+i,function(){
      var sum1 = 0;

      $(".cell"+i).each(function() {
        var get_val = $(this).val();
        sum1 += parseFloat(get_val);
      });

      $("#total_sum_value1").html(sum1);
    });

    i++;
  });

  $("#tbl").on('input','.cell',function(){
    var sum = 0;

    $('.cell').each(function(){
      var get_val = $(this).val();
      sum += parseFloat(get_val);
    });

    $("#total_sum_value").html(sum);
  });
});
```

When you click on the plus sign button, it generates three textboxes. I want to calculate the sum of those textboxes and print it in a span.

Here is a CodePen of my code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XBqKVZ?editors=1010

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are facing? SO is not a free code delivery website. What have you tried?

Comment: I have one button when I click on the button it creates three text boxes now I assign a class to those text boxes. now what I want is a sum of text boxes values and print on span

Comment: @Mr.Black I have updated the answer and its working fine now, can u accept it as the correct answer. thanks

Answer (score 0):

can you try like this:

```
 $('.cell').on('change', function(){
  var sum = 0;
  var data ={
  }

  $('.cell').each(function(index, item){
    var val = $(item).val();
    var get_val = $(this).val();
      sum += Number(get_val);
      console.log(sum);
  });
  $("#total_sum_value").html(sum);
});
```

URL: [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/njb4kspw/23/)

Comment: I'm getting a problem at     $('.cell'+i).each(function(){

Comment: did you try with index, item attributes ?

Comment: sorry I am not much familiar with jquery can you please help me

Comment: have u tried with index item params like i mentioned => .each(function(index, item)

Comment: but I don't know how to do it

Comment: please provide the example in either jsfiddle or jsbin, so that i can update your answer.